# Is it true $ba(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=ab$?

Tags: normal-subgroups

Suppose $G$ is an arbitrary group and $a,b,x,y\in G$. Is the following relationship true? \begin{gather*}ba(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=ab\end{gather*}

Comment: Yes, if the group is commutative. No, if the group is necomuativ.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding @draks post, in $S_3=\{\text{id},~(2,3),~(1,2),~(1,2,3),~(1,3,2),~(1,3)\}$:
$$(2,3)(1,2)[(1,3,2),(1,2,3)]\neq (1,2)(2,3)$$

Comment: Nice counterexample! +)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Commutator#Group_theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Group_theory):

> The commutator of two elements, $g$ and $h$, of a group $G$, is the element
>
> $$   [g, h] = g^{−1}h^{−1}gh.$$
>
> It is equal to the group's identity $e$ if and only if $g$ and $h$ commute...

In your words, if $(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$ for all $a,b,x,y\in G$ then $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab=e$, thus $G$ is commutative.

BTW: It is true for arbitrary groups that *[t]he quotient $G/[G,G]$ is an abelian group called the abelianization of G or G made abelian [[Abelianization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Abelianization)]*